# How to configure apache to disallow users to visit some of the files and directories in the www folder

Tags: apache

I have completed my website but one thing strikes me.
Users can visit all of the sub-directories inside the www/ directory by manipulating the url.

For eg. I have a folder named secret inside the www and a file named start.txt also.
Users in my network can visit and see these by typing url/secret or url/start.txt .

How can this be prohibited ??

One solution is definately to move all those to some other directories out of the www directory.But that would require a lot of effort now .

And I feel there is a way also by modifying the httpd.conf file. Please someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can deny access to certain file types.

Please check this link.
http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types/

Hope this will help you.